# Post data to another aspx page

Tags: asp.net, post, webforms, cross-page-postback

I have simple aspx page that has a form and a input field in it something like below.

**//basket.aspx**

```
<input type="text" id="TotalPrice" runat="server" name="TotalPrice" value="100" />

 <asp:button ID="btnBuy" runat="server" Text="make payment" PostBackUrl="~/payment" />

</form>
```

This is going to **payment.aspx** but when I debug the Request.Form in the page load of the payment.aspx, I cannot reach the TotalPrice value like Request.Form["TotalPrice"]. What is the best way to make a post to another aspx page to get values ? Why the way I am trying to does not work ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using PreviousPage property on the target page.

[Here is an article on how to make cross post backs work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx)